# AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain Code = 5 "'bucket' name can not be empty" in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

1. I am trying to upload  images through aws sdk but when i set AWSS3TransferManager and pass my upload request i got this error. I have tried alot but i got nothing.Below is my upload request
2. `(<AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest: 0x7fa171ff4380> {
   ACL = 0;
   body = "file:///Users/godoctor/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9840DEEA-0D60-48FC-A51E-54FEA77717C7/data/Containers/Data/Application/B1055539-C02A-49D3-BC07-68FBDAB9F6EC/Documents/S3BUpload/2B6EA75E-D0A5-4D3D-9059-005E46A58FBD-58887-0001675A8B149223.png";
   bucket = "qa.test";
   contentType = image;
   currentUploadingPartNumber = 0;
   key = "2B6EA75E-D0A5-4D3D-9059-005E46A58FBD-58887-0001675A8B149223.png";
   requestPayer = 0;
   serverSideEncryption = 0;
   state = 0;
   storageClass = 0;
   totalSuccessfullySentPartsDataLength = 0;
   })`
3. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you have not specified the S3 bucket to upload the data to. You will have to pass that in either in the `uploadRequest1` variable you have created there or instantiate AWSS3TransferManager with the bucket information. AWSS3TransferManager is already deprecated and so if you are still looking for a client library to interact with your S3 resource, I would suggest starting off with AWS Amplify framework's Storage plugin https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage